# Ghostscript change trimbox

Tags: ghostscript

I would like to apply different boxs with ghostscript command line on a file.

I test that for create a new file :
gswin32c -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=file_out.pdf  -c "[/BleedBox [200 200 200 200] /PAGES pdfmark <<  /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [10 10 10 10]  >> setdistillerparams" -f

This code it's ok and create a file with good trimbox/bleedbox.

Now I need to change trimbox on a existing file and i test with this command :
gswin32c -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=file_out_with_trimbox.pdf  -c "[/BleedBox [200 200 200 200] /PAGES pdfmark <<  /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [10 10 10 10]  >> setdistillerparams" -f file_in_without_trimbox.pdf

The new file "file_out_with_trimbox.pdf" content my image pdf but the trimbox/bleedbox doesnt' change.

Can you help me ?

thanks

Comment: OK firstly you aren't setting a TrimBox, you are setting the PDF/X specific PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset, not the same thing. If the incoming file has a TrimBox then it will insert that into the output, which means that you'll end up with both a TrimBox and a PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset. Secondly even if you were to change your pdfmark to write a /TrimBox, it woudn't help because it precedes the input file and is a /PAGES pdfmark. Any page in the input file which has a /TrimBox will override the PAGES pdfmark, because that gets applied to each page as a kind of default.

Comment: Your only option is to create a /EndPage procedure which writes a /PAGE pdfmark with a /TrimBox. because that is executed for each page, after the page is interpreted, it will overwrite any TrimBox from the page with the one in the EndPage.

Comment: Thanks for your return,Can you tell me how do that ?

Comment: For the moment i have juste 1 page on my pdf.

Comment: Something like "<</EndPage {exch pop 2 ne {[/TrimBox [0 0 200 200] /PAGE pdfmark} if}>> setpagedevice". You can look at the PostScript Language Reference Manual for details on EndPage (p427 of the third edition), and you'll need to look at the pdfmark reference (p37 of the version 9 reference) for PAGE pdfmarks. You'll obviously need to change the numbers in the array. I have not tried this code, not least because you haven't supplied an example file to try it with.